# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: apex, soap-api, dynamic-soql, c#

I am trying to fetch all the attachments for a record from salesforce by .Net webservice.

Below is the code which i am trying to do. If i am fetching a single attachment, i am not facing any issue. But if there are multiple attachment,i am unable to fetch and i am getting the below error -

```
'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at WcfService1.Service1.ConnectSalesforce() in C:\Users\mohapats\source\repos\WcfService1\WcfService1\Service1.svc.cs:line 149
   at WcfService1.Service1.CombineMultiplePDFs(List`1 InFiles, String OutFile) in C:\Users\mohapats\source\repos\WcfService1\WcfService1\Service1.svc.cs:line 59'
```

c# code -

```
if(currentLoginResult.sessionId != null)
            {
                QueryResult queryResult = null;
                String SOQL = "SELECT Id FROM Attachment where ParentId = '0010v0000071CHp'";
                queryResult = sfdcBinding.query(SOQL);
                List<String> ids = new List<String>();

                if (queryResult.size > 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++) { 

                    Attachment readAttatchmentId = (Attachment)queryResult.records[i];
                    ids.Add(readAttatchmentId.Id);
                    }
                }

                if(ids.Count > 0)
                {
                    //QueryResult queryResult1 = null;
                    //String SOQL1 = "SELECT Id,Body,Name FROM Attachment where Id = '" + ids + "'";
                    //queryResult1 = sfdcBinding.query(SOQL1);
                    String query = "SELECT Id,Body,Name FROM Attachment ";

                    String strIds = "";
                    foreach (String  id in ids)
                    {
                        if (strIds.Equals(""))
                        {
                            strIds = "'" + id + "'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strIds += ",'" + id + "'";
                        }
                    }
                    query += "where id in (" + strIds + ")";

                    QueryResult result = sfdcBinding.query(query);
                                        Boolean done = false;



 if (result.size > 0)
                {
                    while (!done)
                    {
                        sObject[] records = result.records;
                        for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            Attachment q = (Attachment)records[i];

                        }
                        if (result.done)
                        {
                            done = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = sfdcBinding.queryMore(result.queryLocator);
                        }
                    }

                }
```

The below soql -

```
QueryResult result = sfdcBinding.query(query);
```

This should return two arrays

```
result.records[0] & result.records[1]
```

but it is returning only one

```
result.records[0]
```

but `result.size`  is showing as `2`

So at the below line

```
Attachment q = (Attachment)result.records[i];
```

when it comes for the 2nd time, it throws the above error.

Comment: problem is that result and result[i].record can have different length. It is exactly what happens in your c# code

Comment: Hi kurunve.. is there any way to resolve this..

Answer (score 3):

You've run into the query result paging where the size of the SOQL query result `size` will be greater than then number of records returned in the current QueryResult.

When dealing with Attachments it's not uncommon for the QueryResult to only have a single record.

> The query result object contains up to 500 rows of data by default. If the query results exceed 500 rows, then the client application uses the queryMore() call and a server-side cursor to retrieve additional rows in 500-row chunks. You can increase the default size up to 2,000 in the QueryOptions header. For more details see [Change the Batch Size in Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm) in the Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference. [[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm)]

You need to check if `done` is true. If not, use the `queryLocator` to fetch the next lot of results until `done` turns false.

See:

- [queryMore()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm)
- [C# example code using queryMore()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#highlighter_507973)

Comment: Hi Daniel.. Can u check the above code and let me know if i have written correctly... i have updated it..

Comment: @learningmode Your initial `queryResult` isn't checking if it is done and seems a bit redundant. Why not just perform a single SOQL query to get the attachments (with the body field) based on the ParentId? Otherwise, yes, from what I can see it should work through all the query results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop through the result rows directly and avoid potential indexing errors altogether?

```
if(result.size() > 0){
    for(sObject record : result.records){
        Attachment q = (Attachment)record;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi .. RenegadeCoder.. after updating my code.. i am still getting only 1 record in my array..